# How can I display a list to mimic that of a select?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a select statement with options set up so that a user selects a member to promote to a 'team leader.' It's set up as a multiselect so that it shows some users and you can scroll down after the list gets too big.

The trouble is, eventually this list will be populated with hundreds of users, so I'd prefer for it to be able to be filtered by a user.

I found a way to filter it when it's a list, and it works perfectly, but when I research online with how to style, filter, and hide options within a select statement, most of the responses I get say that's it's a bad idea to try and format select statements, since different browsers and operating systems interpret them differently.

That being the case, is there a way to format a select statement and option such that it's a list instead (and it turns into a scrollable box at a certain point so that 100 aren't displayed all visibly at one time)?

Comment: What you are proposing is far too complicated. Try using something like [Twitter's typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) instead, to keep the size of the options manageable. It is very fast and optimized for this use case exactly.

Comment: yeah do what @Two-BitAlchemist said. it is the easiest way. I modified this control http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/, to fill its options with only 10 records that match the search box. but it is not that easy to use or share.